# Pre-Fill Dialog box using FBConnect?

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog, fbconnect

A few months ago I used to be able to pre-fill the dialog box with my own text so the user would only have to click share to share that text but it seems that Facebook has started to ignore that parameter like they say in this post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/

So is there any other way around it so I can pre-fill a message that the user can easily share?

Thanks!

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    [super webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];

    if (defaultStatus)
    {
        // Set the pre-filled status message
        [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByName('feedform_user_message')[0].value = decodeURIComponent('%@')",
          [SHKEncode(defaultStatus) stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"]
         ]
        ];

        // Make the text field bigger
        [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByName('feedform_user_message')[0].style.height='100px'"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik it is not possible anymore to pre-fill the message box with the javascript api, which is a good thing. after all it is against the platform policies:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/application_integration_points/

but: it should still be possible with the php api/sdk. you just have to allow the user to edit the message before you send it, with a textarea or input field. just make a post to /me/feed with the message parameter.

Comment: So there is no other way to do this? What if my app relies on this heavily?

Comment: Can you show some example code just so I get on the right track? Then I will up vote and accept your answer! :)

Comment: check my code above, that code doesn't work at the moment but how would I modify it so it does work?

Comment: I ended up just going with taking a screenshot on the device of the text and doing it that way since it is 100% easier!